# How to convert created_time field value to date from Instagram media object in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got from my JSON media object response

> "created_time": "1279340983"

(instagram api), How to convert it to normal `DateTime` in **Android Studio** project

Comment: is it millisecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public String getDate() {
  long ms = Long.parseLong("1279340983", 10) // your data created_time
  Date date = new Date(ms);
  SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
  return dateformat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ms = 1279340983; // created_time
        Date date = new Date(ms);
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
        System.out.println(dateformat.format(date));
    }
```